# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake', even through cmake is installed

Tags: python, cmake

I am trying to install the Python Lib 'Mapping', but when it tries to install 'osqp' i get the following Error:  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cmake'. But 'cmake' is installed and when i run 'pip freeze' i find it, also i am able to use 'import cmake' without any errors.
What could be the issue?
Thanks.

I tried to reinstall cmake and reboot the Laptop, but it didn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please try to [provide us with a procedure to reproduce the issue you are encountering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score -1):

unfortunatelly, this problem is not very often. May you can try to reinstall it and clean the ide. All the best

Comment: Note: The question post already said they tried to reinstall and reboot and it didn't work.